# How do I extract the following patterns in java

Tags: java, regex

I have string in following format:

```
String s = " some text....
    [[Category:Anarchism| ]]
[[Category:Political culture]]
[[Category:Political ideologies]]
[[Category:Far-left politics]]
... some more text"
```

I want to extract all the categories from this text. `[Anarchism,Political culture ....,Far-left politics]`

Also, is there a good tutorial where I can learn about this regex pattern matching stuff..
Thanks

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is best I've seen so far if you want to learn about pure regex, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ will tell you how to use regex in Java. To solve this question you will need to know how to use Pattern and Matcher classes, what characters are special in regex and how to escape it (`[` and `]` in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to select the  word "Category" itself, the regex would be:

```
(?<=Category:).*?(?=])
```

I'll break this down a bit for you.

The first bit in brackets looks for `Category`, without actually selecting it.

Next `.+?` looks for 1-infinity characters (other than a newline), but stops as soon as the next part is matched:

The final brackets tells it to look for a `]`, but without actually selecting it.

The results would be the bits below highlighted in blue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to get categories:

```
\[\[Category:(.+)\]\]
```

Then you can access to your groups to get the category values.

Remember to add backslash to backslashes if you use on java strings:

```
\\[\\[Category:(.+)\\]\\]
```

You can see it working:

[image]